# How to remove div in cross site div?

Tags: javascript, postmessage, cross-site

I have an iframe youtube video, where i want to remove an div element. 
I can do it in in the console as long I manually folded out the div which I am looking for, but otherwise i am not able to find it using `document.getElementByClassName()`..

Is it possible via js to somehow remove an div which resides inside #document?

Comment: no such thing as `getElementByClassName` - it's `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Even if this was possible, you would likely be breaking YouTube's terms of use by modifying their player.

Answer (score 0):

No.

JavaScript running in a page containing an iframe element can't access the DOM of a cross-origin site loaded into that iframe.

You *can* send messages using postMessage, but YouTube has no API for removing arbitrary elements from the DOM in response to a message.